# "Ignore this user (everywhere)" doesn't affect star board

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars, ignored-users

Using "ignore this user (everywhere)" option in chat hides all messages from selected user in the feed.

> [image: User menu]

But it doesn't affect star board. I.e. if ignored user has starred message it's visible anyway.

Is it normal behaviour for such option?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is a bug.